# Trying to get react-native-calendars TimelineList working

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-calendars

I'm at a loss at this point.  I've been trying for days to render my TimelineList calendar. For some reason the items are not showing up.  My code is a little crazy at this point trying multiple things.  If anyone has any thoughts I would appreciate it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  SafeAreaView,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native";

import {
  Calendar,
  Agenda,
  Timeline,
  ExpandableCalendar,
  TimelineList,
  CalendarProvider,
} from "react-native-calendars";
import Modal from "react-native-modal";
import FlightItem from "./FlightItem";
import UserStore from "../stores/UserStore";
import ReservationForm from "./ReservationForm";
import { db } from "../FirebaseConfig";
import {
  collection,
  addDoc,
  query,
  where,
  getDocs,
  onSnapshot,
  deleteDoc,
  doc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { formatISO } from "date-fns";

const CalendarComponent = () => {
  const userDetails = UserStore;
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(
    formatISO(new Date(), { representation: "date" })
  );
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [selectedFlight, setSelectedFlight] = useState(null);
  const [editingReservation, setEditingReservation] = useState(null);
  //const [items, setItems] = useState({});
  const [items, setItems] = useState({ [selectedDate]: [] });

  const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false); // Move this line here
  //console.log(userDetails);
  const userID = userDetails.userID;

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentDate = formatISO(new Date(), { representation: "date" });
    if (currentDate) {
      loadReservations(currentDate);
    }

    const reservationsRef = collection(db, "reservations");
    const q = query(reservationsRef);
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
      const reservations = {};
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data();
        const date = data.date;

        if (!reservations[date]) {
          reservations[date] = [];
        }

        reservations[date].push({
          id: doc.id,
          start: data.startTime,
          end: data.endTime,
          title: `Aircraft: ${data.selectedAircraftValue}\n${data.firstName} ${data.lastName}`,
          color: aircraftColors[data.selectedAircraftValue] || "#000000",
        });
      });
      console.log("Updated reservations:", reservations);
      setItems(reservations);
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [refresh]);

  const onDayPress = (day) => {
    if (day.dateString) {
      setSelectedDate(day.dateString);
      loadReservations(day.dateString);
    }
  };

  const onBookFlight = () => {
    setEditingReservation(null);
    setIsModalVisible(true);
  };

  const aircraftColors = {
    N2875Z: "#FF0000",
    N6351Q: "#00FF00",
    N67890: "#0000FF",
    // Add more aircraft and colors as needed
  };

  const onEditReservation = (reservation) => {
    setEditingReservation(reservation);
    setIsModalVisible(true);
  };

  const loadReservations = async (date) => {
    const reservationsRef = collection(db, "reservations");
    const q = query(reservationsRef, where("date", "==", date));

    try {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      const newItems = { ...items };

      newItems[date] = [];

      await Promise.all(
        querySnapshot.docs.map(async (doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          const { id } = doc;

          newItems[date].push({
            id,
            start: data.startTime,
            end: data.endTime,
            title: `Aircraft ${data.selectedAircraftValue || "N/A"}\n${
              data.firstName
            } ${data.lastName}`,
            color: aircraftColors[data.selectedAircraftValue] || "#000000",
          });
        })
      );

      setItems(newItems);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching reservations: ", error);
    }
  };

  const addOrUpdateReservation = async (date, reservation) => {
    const reservationData = {
      date,
      userID: userDetails.userID,
      firstName: userDetails.first,
      lastName: userDetails.last,
      club: userDetails.club,
      ...reservation,
      selectedAircraftValue: reservation.selectedAircraftValue, // Add this line
    };

    try {
      await addDoc(collection(db, "reservations"), reservationData);
      setIsModalVisible(false);
      setRefresh(!refresh); // Add this line to force a re-render
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error adding reservation: ", error);
    }
  };

  const handleDelete = async (id) => {
    // Delete the reservation from the database
    try {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, "reservations", id));
      setIsModalVisible(false);
      setRefresh(!refresh);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error deleting reservation: ", error);
    }
  };

  const onModalClose = () => {
    setSelectedFlight(null);
    setIsModalVisible(false);
    setEditingReservation(null);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      {/* ...existing components... */}
      <CalendarProvider
        date={selectedDate}
        onDateChanged={onDayPress}
        showTodayButton
        disabledOpacity={0.6}
      >
        <ExpandableCalendar firstDay={1} />
        <TimelineList
          events={items[selectedDate] || []}
          timelineProps={{
            format24h: true,
            unavailableHours: [
              { start: 0, end: 6 },
              { start: 22, end: 24 },
            ],
            overlapEventsSpacing: 8,
            rightEdgeSpacing: 24,
          }}
          showNowIndicator
          initialTime={{ hour: 9, minutes: 0 }}
          onEventPress={(event) => {
            console.log("Event pressed:", event);
          }}
        />
      </CalendarProvider>

      {/* Add Reservation Button */}
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.addReservationButton}
        onPress={onBookFlight}
      >
        <Text style={styles.addReservationButtonText}>+</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* Rest of your components */}

      <Modal isVisible={isModalVisible} onBackdropPress={onModalClose}>
        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.modalTitle}>
            {editingReservation ? "Edit Reservation" : "New Reservation"}
          </Text>
          <ReservationForm
            selectedAircraftValue={
              editingReservation ? editingReservation.selectedAircraftValue : ""
            }
            onSave={(reservation) => {
              addOrUpdateReservation(selectedDate, reservation);
            }}
            onCancel={() => setIsModalVisible(false)}
            onDelete={() =>
              handleDelete(editingReservation ? editingReservation.id : "")
            }
            editingReservation={editingReservation}
            editing={Boolean(editingReservation)} // Add this line
          />
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF",
  },
  modalContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 20,
  },
  modalTitle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  modalText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  modalButtons: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
  },
  modalButton: {
    padding: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#2196F3",
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  modalButtonText: {
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  emptyDataContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: 10,
  },
  emptyDataText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "#777",
  },
  header: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#2196F3",
  },
  headerTitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  headerButton: {
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  headerButtonText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "#2196F3",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  addReservationButton: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 20,
    right: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#2196F3",
    borderRadius: 50,
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    zIndex: 10,
  },
  addReservationButtonText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 40,
  },
});

export default CalendarComponent;
```

here is the logged data that comes through.

Updated reservations: {"2023-04-21": [{"color": "#FF0000", "end": "17:42", "id": "3DKiauB0flrGTLQhCIRc", "start": "16:42", "title": "Aircraft: N3498G
Bob Lastname"}]